# Android, load mp3 on first activity and access it on activity further down

Tags: android, soundpool

Is there a way to load a MP3 file into the soundpool in activity 1, then access it further down in activity 5?

I have been trying this with no success.

This is of course to cut down on load times and use the same files all over the place without loading them over and over and over again

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use services for that matter.
Services can run in the background regardless of activities states.
Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

You can initialize the soundpool in the service and access it via your activities.